# Asp.net core 3.1 502.5 error on Plesk web hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-hosting, plesk-onyx

I'm really new to the ASP.NET environment. After deploying my ASP.NET Core 3.1 to the Plesk web hosting through Visual studio 2019, Firstly, it responds an error "500.21 Internal server error" and finds the solution for that error on google and I changed the "AspNetCoreModuleV2" to "AspNetCoreModule" in the [web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mtjg.png) file. but I still respond to an error as "502.5 - Process Failure error". Hope someone could help me. [502.5 Http error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJd9C.png). here is my  [IIS Application pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHn5U.png) and [IIS Setting fig-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNp8N.png) [IIS Setting fig-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNHpe.png)

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for it? Because I have the same problem. Regards Timo

Comment: nobody answered me for that solution. and I still do not know what to do with it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of your problem. You need to turn off the setting here: Tools & Settings / Security Policy and then the "Prohibit the ability to override handlers via web.config" checkbox.

Regards
Timo